# Database used in website and local program

Tags: c#, php, database, local

i want to use a database SQL in phpmyadmin (for a website) and also use it for a local program (with Visual Studio 2008 C#)

I try to search for informations but i found nothing, i dont know what to do. If someone can refer me.
I already do my website with a .sql database.

I want to use the same database in a website (with phpmyadmin) and a local program (Visual Studio 2008 in C#)

Thanks

Comment: You want to write sql code for use in a VC# program? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: +1 @Marc B & "do my website with a .sql database" which DBMS/dialect? AFTER EDIT: So your question is, how to access a database from C#!?

Comment: @Hulk "Im french man" What should that tell us? Independent of your nationality, you may use any SQL-database from nearly every (programming-)language, for MySQL for example see here: [Using MySQL With .NET/C#/Visual Basic/Powershell](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/dotnet/) or here [PHP - MySQLi](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or here [PHP PDO](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where you are hosting your site, you may need to specify in your MySQL control panel that you would like your database accessible by other sites (IP addresses). Once you're sure you have that configured correctly, you would connect to your database just like you would a locally hosted one with the exception of a remote host address.

You will need to look in your MySQL control panel for what that host name is. For example, GoDaddy uses something like `username.xxxxxx.hostedresource.com` in their host address naming convention for their grid accounts. If you have any problems locating this info, just contact your host. You would use the same username and password as your website does.